# SQL Server 2012 DECLARE Performance scenarios

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, query-performance, declare, sql-execution-plan

I have a very quick question. I have to declare many variables (about 50).
Which of the following queries will be faster, query1 or query2?

Query #1:

```
DECLARE @var1 int,
        @var2 int,
        @var3 int, ....
```

Query #2:

```
DECLARE @var1 int
DECLARE @var2 int
DECLARE @var3 int ....
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
DECLARE @var1 int;
DECLARE @var2 int;
DECLARE @var3 int;
```

Is same as below, just **syntactic sugar**:

```
DECLARE @var1 int,
        @var2 int,
        @var3 int, ....
```

*Warning: When you initialize variables that depends on previous variable:*

```
DECLARE @a INT = 1
        ,@b INT = @a + 1;

SELECT @b;
```

> Must declare the scalar variable "@a".

You need to use:

```
DECLARE @a INT = 1;
DECLARE @b INT = @a + 1;

SELECT @b;
```

Comment: Did you measure it? How do you know there is no performance difference?

Comment: @usr Same 50%/50% on execution plans. And the definition of syntactic sugar indicates it is the same. But if you know counterexample I will correct my answer.

Comment: The execution plan indicates estimated cost according to a model. It's not necessary what is executed physically. Not all syntactic sugar is free.